# mailgun rails - How to define mailgun_settings per ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, mailgun

I am using [mailgun-ruby](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-ruby) to send emails in my rails app.

I have activated a number of domains on my Mailgun account and for each ActionMailer I wish to choose a specific domain to send emails from.

The gem's documentation only explains a global way of setting mailgun_settings:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method  = :mailgun
config.action_mailer.mailgun_settings = {
  api_key: 'api-myapikey',
  domain:  'mydomain.com'
}
```

Any suggestion how this can be done per ActionMailer?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a self crafted design for this:

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  before_action do
    @layout  = 'mailer'
    @from    = 'default@domain.com'
    @to      = 'default_to@domain.com'
    @subject = 'Default Subject'
    @domain  = 'default.domain.com'
    @params  = {}
  end

  after_action do
    ac = ActionController::Base.new()
    mg = Mailgun::Client.new 'key-xxxxxxxxx'
    message_params =  { 
      from:    @from,
      to:      @to,
      subject: @subject,
      text:    ac.render_to_string("#{self.class.to_s.underscore}/#{action_name}.text", layout: @layout, locals: @params),
      html:    ac.render_to_string("#{self.class.to_s.underscore}/#{action_name}.html", layout: @layout, locals: @params)
    }
    mg.send_message @domain, message_params
  end
end


class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  before_action do
    @from = 'Domain <updates@domain.com>'
    @domain = 'updates.domain.com'
  end

  def test
    @to = "yourself@gmail.com"
    @subject = "Test"
    @params = {}
  end
end
```

Customize `user_mailer/test.txt.erb` and `user_mailer/test.html.erb` and send the email:

```
 UserMailer.test
```